# integrate : $\displaystyle\int \frac{x^2}{(3+4x-4x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx$

Tags: integration

could somebody give me a hint on how to integrate this :  $$\displaystyle\int \frac{x^2}{(3+4x-4x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx$$
I have the impression that I must do some polynomial division but i have no idea to be honest.

Comment: I would complete the square, get $4-(2x-1)^2$. Then let $2x-1=2\sin\theta$.

Comment: you got 2x-1=2sin x by constructing a right triangle right ?

Comment: $2x-1=2\sin\theta$.  And in this case I did not use a right triangle, because I have seen this sort of expression many times. However, until it becomes unnecessary, drawing a triangle is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$=\int\frac{x^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mux}{\bigl(4-(2x-1)^2\bigr)^{\tfrac32}}=\frac18\underbrace{\int\frac{x^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mux}{\Bigl(1-\bigl(x-\frac12\bigr)^2\Bigr)^{\tfrac32}}}_I$$

and use substitution: $\; x=\sin t+\frac12$. You get:
\begin{align*}
I&=\int\frac{(\sin^2t+\sin t+\frac14)\cos t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mut}{\cos^3t}=\int\tan^2t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mut+\int\frac{\sin t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mut}{\cos^2t}+\frac14\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mut}{\cos^2t}\\[1ex]
&=\tan t-t+\frac1{\cos t} +\frac14\tan t=\frac{5\sin t+4}{4\cos t}-t\\[1ex]
&=\frac{10x+3}{\sqrt{3+4x-4x^2}}-\arcsin\Bigl(x-\frac12\Bigr)
\end{align*}